# SQL bulk insert of CSV with 5.4M rows only loads 1048575 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm trying to bulk insert the contents of a CSV into a table in SQL (which I then merge into another table to update data, or add new rows).

The CSV has 5.4M rows and my SQL bulk insert returns no errors or warnings but only loads the first 1048575 rows of data (if I use the SSIS wizard it consumes all 5.4M rows, but I need this to be T-SQL which runs daily).

```
bulk insert destination_table 
from 'path\filename.csv' 
with (
      format = 'CSV', 
      firstrow = 2, 
      fieldterminator = ',', 
      rowterminator = '0x0A'
     )
```

Any ideas why it stops at the Excel row limit?

Comment: Any error message, log or something? Another suggestion to diagnose the problem is to cut the file right before the 1048575 row and try to import it, if it stops that meas you have a problem on your file. Take a look at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/prepare-data-for-bulk-export-or-import-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: No errors, no warnings, just a completed message. As I say works for all 5.4M if I use the SSIS wizard, only loads 1048575 rows using bulk insert.

Comment: Add the `ERRORFILE` argument to collect any faulty rows in an error file. I suspect there is an empty line or header at the 1M row mark. Or it could be an incorrectly quoted string.

Comment: Since (as you noted) that's the Excel file size limit... I assume this CSV is created by combining multiple Excel files? As others have noted, it's probably an issue with that row. If someone has combined Excel files, it's probably a header or terminator in the middle. You could also try adding logging (or maybe batch size) and see if there is an error or any different behavior.

Comment: Conversely, you could check your table where your data was successfully inserted via the wizard and see if there's a blank row, or rows with header data in them instead of data values.

Comment: There's no 1M row limit in BULK INSERT. Without knowing what the file looks like or what happens at row 1048575 and later, we can only guess. You could try reading the file in Excel's PowerPivot and see whether it complains. The 1M row limit is only for Sheet rows. PowerPivot is only limited by RAM. Or you could write a small console app using CsvHelper to see whether it complains and what the "bad" rows look like

Comment: Added ERRORFILE - no errors and no file created

Comment: @RichHead did you specify the *full* path for the error file? The documentation says `The error file is created when the command is executed. An error occurs if the file already exists.`

Comment: @JacobH - no, it's the output from a WPS (SAS) process and just normal data at and around row 1048575 in the table from SSIS (or in the CSV if I search using Notepad)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - yes full path

Comment: I'm baffled - not least because SSIS handled it fine.

Comment: did you try my suggestion on cutting the file right before that number and try to bulk import it to see what happens?

Comment: @jorge, unfortunately I don't seem to have an app with line numbers and the organisation has locked down all PC to prevent installations, so no...